# Something changing my URLS

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

When trying to access my site's index.php by going to my root directory (domain.com). I am being redirected to

`domain.com/.php`

And then I receive a 403 forbidden error. I completely erased my .htaccess file to try and fix the problem but it still persists. Is there anything else that could be redirecting me?

Comment: Sometimes .htaccess is not deleted as it shows ! make sure to check hidden files too.

Answer (score 0):

First things that come to mind:

- .htaccess file still exists (maybe just not displayed, see @Behrad Khodayar's comment)
- index file redirects to .php (filename missing/blank for some reason)
- apache2.conf or .htaccess on a higher directory level has set **DirectoryIndex .php** (instead of default value **DirectoryIndex index.php**)